# Can we time travel to the past physically?

Tags: internal-consistency, time-travel

What is the most scientifically realistic way to accomplish time travel?

Comment: I still cannot specify the actual site in the 'pick the site you think this belongs on instead' option.  But if you just want to know what the state of the art in physics has to say about this, https://physics.stackexchange.com/ seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

**Most probably no, but you can use semi-plausible alternatives**

From what science knows today, the only form of time-travel is forward, through use of relativistic speeds that can slow down the passage of time for the user.

What I think you should do is only semi-unrealistic (it has backings in science, but it most likely impossible). Let’s say the characters in your story just travel around opening up ancient *wormholes*. When opening these up, they can travel back to the date of the creation of said wormholes. And it’ll be more exciting, since the era the time travelers will arrive in will be randomized.

Maybe they could use a combination of both, using *really* old wormholes to travel back into the early ages of the universe, and then using relativity (and suspended animation) to fly by every era of history they wish to visit.

To add more suspense, make the wormholes unstable. Like, if they try and change to much history, they risk being “erased” by the wormholes they use.

Answer (score 1):

The only semi plausibe way to achieve time travel is through a process called ["Frame Dragging"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging), which involves supermassive objects moving at relatavistic velocities (technically, frame dragging can occur anywhere, but the frame dragging of the entire Earth is so small it takes specialized instruments to measure it).

The ["T" Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipler_cylinder) is such a device, theorized as cylinder of neutron star material spinning at nearly the speed of light. The massive frame dragging is enough to pull "[light cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone)" well away from thier normal orientation, pointing foreard and backward into time and space. One side effect is you are actually going to "otherwhen" and it isn't entirely clear if you leave this Universe you ever can come back....

[image]

*Light cone*

[image]

*T Machine at work*

The other issue with T machines is they can only send you as far back in time as their activation - if some scientist creates one in 3204 AD, then that is the farthest date in the past that will be accessable to someone using it in the 40th millenium. To kill Hitler or do any of the other thhings often fantasized about in time travel would require the discovery of a working T machine which was activated sometime in our past. Once again, since the machine points to "otherwhen", you may end up in a 1933 Earth where Hitler was never born...

It *may* be possible that the conditions theorized by Tipler could be replicated by natural astrophysical objects, such as the super massive black holes near the center of most galaxies, but this hasn't been rigerously explored to my knowledge, and the other conditions surrounding black holes, like the highly energetic accretion disks might make going there hazardous to the time traveler. Being roasted by high energy X rays before getting close enough to experience frame dragging isn't going to make time travel very popular.

[image]

*Just a bit closer....*

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

The only form of time travel is forwards only. The two ways of doing this is suspended animation, or going on a really fast ship at relativistic speeds.

and there's evidence backwards time travel is impossible: the atrocities of history still remain

Comment: Nah, all serious atrocities of history has already been fixed. Whatever remains is nothing compared to what had had been.

Comment: What if the actual atrocities were erased, but the memory of the atrocities needed to continue to preserve causality? Kind of like Millenium, the movie where they were rescuing victims of plane crashes to colonize the future.